# What is the JPA implementation in this guide?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, netbeans

I followed this NetBeans guide here on RESTful web services using JPA - http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/rest.html

I thought JPA was supposed to be a specification and you would use something like Hibernate as the actual implementation in your application. But this guide doesn't make any mention of an implementation at all. So where is the implementation coming from, is NetBeans providing its own JPA implementation?

Comment: You can use any JPA implementation with Glassfish, so why does any tutorial on JPA need to mention which one is being used? It's for you, the user, to select the one you prefer for your project, based on what you're trying to do, and what bugs the implementation has (or not).

Comment: A tutorial doesn't need to mention it but I want to understand what is happening behind the scenes and I couldn't find what JPA was being used from looking at the source code so I asked here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That tutorial uses Glassfish as the Application Server. It provides the implementations for the JavaEE Apis, and in the case of JPA, it is EclipseLink. The idea is that your application does not ship with those libraries (JARs) and instead rely on the ones provided by the Application Server

Once you have it working, if you wish to learn about different JPA implementations, or different Application Servers, then you can try running the same application on JBoss, which has Hibernate as its JPA implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably it is the JPA provided by the container (probably Glassfish).